# Get the right vectors in a differential equation system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm stuck with this differential equation system:

$
Y'(x) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
Y(x)
$

I get only one eigenvalue, $\lambda = 2$ (with algebraic multiplicity 3).

For this eigenvalue, I obtain:

$
Y'(x) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \Rightarrow
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
v_{x}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

I just got only one eigenvector, so that I've to get two more.

I look for:

$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \Rightarrow
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

From this, I choose the vector $(0,1,0)$

To get the last vector, I do:

$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}^2
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \Rightarrow
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    v_{z} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    v_{x} \\
    v_{y} \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

From this, I choose the vector $(0,0,1)$

So that, I think with these three (and linearly independent) vectors I should get the general solution like this:

$
y(x) =
    C_{1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    \frac{C_{3}x^2}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
$

But this is not correct since it doesn't proove the initial relation. I get for both sides of the initial relation:

$
Y'(x) = 
    C_{1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    \frac{C_{3}x^2}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
$

And

$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    Y(x) = 
    C_{1}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    \frac{C_{3}x^2}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}x
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
    +
    C_{3}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    -1 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    e^{2x}
$

I'm almost sure that I get the eigenvectors wrongly but I don't know how to get it right...

Please, anybody knows where is the error and what should I do in order to get the right vectors?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use that expression for getting the vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of your differential equation are of the form$$Y(t)=k\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\0&2&-1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}\right).\tag1$$Now, note that$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\0&2&-1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}=2\operatorname{Id}+\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and that this expresses$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\0&2&-1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$as the sum of two commuting matrices. Therefore, $(1)$ is equal to$$k\exp(2t\operatorname{Id})\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right).$$But\begin{align}\exp\left(t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\operatorname{Id}+t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\frac1{2!}\left(t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)^2+\cdots\\&=\operatorname{Id}+t\begin{bmatrix}0&1&3\\0&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\frac{t^2}2\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1&t&3t-\frac{t^2}2\\0&1&-t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: I like very much the way you get it José Carlos, but my I must get the solution doing the differential equation step by step.

Comment: @cooper That is exactly what I did.

Comment: My apologize for the bad explanation. Is there any other way of getting the vectors you get?. My teacher explained us that we've to get the vectors with the expression: "((A-lambda·I)^n) · v = v1". In the end you get 5 different vectors and I get just three, so that the way I'm doing is completely wrong

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. There are no vectors whatsoever in my answer.